# Calling Server.MapPath from .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, stream, server.mappath

I'm trying to write my errors into the text file in my MapPath.
But i have a problem it is :

```
path = Server.MapPath("~/emails.txt");
```

Actually `Server` is in `System.Web.UI.Page` namespace and I want to Use it in my cs file which has no aspx file... I  mean it is CodeFile in AppCode;
How can I write to file from cs CodeFile?

Comment: I've changed title to match you question - feel free to edit/revert. Note that you'll hit `IOException`/"access denied" exceptions - search for similar questions to find how to setup permissions for this to succeed, OR use existing logging libraries - again many topics on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Server`.